# Вывести ошибку из слушателя

Tags: javascript, listener

#### Описание

В проекте есть некая конструкция `try { } catch`. Проблема в том, что, если ошибка возникает внутри слушателя, то `try` его не ловит. Пример

```js
try {
  document.querySelector(`button#a`).addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
    const a = 5;
    a = 8;
  });
} catch (error) {
  document.write(`Ошибка '${error}' была поймана!`);
}
```

```html
<button id="a">Click to call error</button>
```

При чем, это не касается обычных функций, даже анонимных.

```js
try {
  (() => {
    const a = 5;
    a = 8;
  })();
} catch (error) {
  document.write(`Ошибка '${error}' была поймана!`);
}
```

#### Вопрос

Почему ошибки в слушателей ускользают от `try`?
Как такие ошибки тоже поймать при помощи `try`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не возможно, т.к. слушатели - это асинхронные функции. Асинхронные функции возвращают промисы, а это не ошибка, даже если возвращается `Promise.reject`

Даже если взять ваш же пример с анонимной функцией и сделать его аснхронным, то ошибки не будет

```js
try {
  (async () => {
    const a = 5;
    a = 8;
  })();
} catch (error) {
  document.write(`Ошибка '${error}' была поймана!`);
}
```

Если эта была бы обычная функция, то я могу показать как поймать ошибку извне, но я не знаю как `await`-тить слушатели :)

Можно например ловить ошибку в асинхронной функции:

```js
async function asyncError() {
    throw new Error("Error from asyncError()");
}

async function catchError() {
    try {
        await asyncError();
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

catchError();
```

Или например использовать синтаксис `then..catch`:

```js
async function asyncError() {
    throw new Error("Error from asyncError()");
}

asyncError()
    .catch(console.error)
```

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, информацию о том как поймать ошибки в асинхронных функциях, если они не являются слушателями.

Comment: А в примере с анон-ой функцией и так всё хендлилось.

Comment: @eccs0103 Добавил

Answer (score 0):

По моему ловит если правильно использовать:

```js
document.querySelector(`button#a`).addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
  try {
    const a = 5;
    a = 8;
  } catch (error) {
    document.write(`Ошибка '${error}' была поймана!`);
  }
});


// Пример для более точного понимания
function foo() {
  // Ошибка произойдет
  // здесь поэтому и ловить ее нужно здесь.
  try {
    const a = 5;
    a = 8;
  } catch (error) {
    document.write(`Караул ошибка '${error}' хотя она была поймана!`);
  }
}

document.querySelector(`button#a1`).addEventListener(`click`, foo);
```

```html
<div><button id="a">Click to call error</button></div>
<div><button id="a1">Click to call error</button></div>
```

Comment: Это вы `try { } catch` внутри слушателя перенесли. Так и у меня работает. Смысл вопроса в том чтобы `try { } catch` писать снаружи и один раз, а так придется для каждого слушателя отдельный писать.

Comment: Вот вопросы: `Почему ошибки в слушателей ускользают от try? Как такие ошибки тоже поймать при помощи try?`, поправляйте ответ, у вас на данный момент ответа на текущие вопросы нет.

Comment: Так как Вы написали код вопроса делать нельзя я вам об этом написал. Ошибка происходит в анонимной функции, а не у слушателя событий потому он не ловит ничего. Воспроизведите ошибку в самом слушателе и ответ будет об этом. А так ответ соответствует заданному вопросу.

Comment: @Andrei можете, пожалуйста, добавить запятые для комментария? Очень тяжело читать. (Начало)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Извините. Не могу отредактировать  так как время редактирования истекло. Сайт не дает отредактировать.

Comment: @Andrei в принципе не страшно, суть комментария всё равно понятна.